# Sending a message with C# works locally but silently fails live

Tags: c#, asp.net, gmail

I am using the following code to send a booking form but it is working locally but when I put it live it fails and not sure why:

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void SendMail()
    {
        var sDate = startDate.Text;
        var eDate = endDate.Text;

        // Gmail Address from where you send the mail
        var fromAddress = "xxx@googlemail.com";
        // any address where the email will be sending
        var toAddress = "silverhillcattery@hotmail.co.uk";
        //Password of your gmail address
        const string fromPassword = "xxx";
        // Passing the values and make a email formate to display
        string subject = YourSubject.Text.ToString();
        string body = "From: " + YourName.Text + "\n";
        body += "Email: " + YourEmail.Text + "\n";
        body += "Contact Number: " + txtContactNumber.Text + "\n";
        body += "Subject: " + YourSubject.Text + "\n";
        body += "Question: \n" + Comments.Text + "\n";
        body += "Pet Name(s): \n" + txtPetName.Text + "\n";
        body += "Start Date: \n" + sDate + "\n";
        body += "End Date: \n" + eDate + "\n";

        // smtp settings
        var smtp = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient();
        {
            smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
            smtp.Port = 587;
            smtp.EnableSsl = true;
            smtp.DeliveryMethod = System.Net.Mail.SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromAddress, fromPassword);
            smtp.Timeout = 20000;
        }
        // Passing values to smtp object
        smtp.Send(fromAddress, toAddress, subject, body);
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            //here on button click what will done 
            SendMail();
            DisplayMessage.Text = "Thank you for contacting us we will get back to you shortly.  If you would like to talk to us, please call 0208 236 9572";
            DisplayMessage.Visible = true;
            YourSubject.Text = "";
            YourEmail.Text = "";
            YourName.Text = "";
            Comments.Text = "";
        }
        catch (Exception) { }
    }
```

It doesn't send the message or display the "Thank you for contacting..."

This is the site www.silverhillcattery.co.uk

Any help would be much appreciated!

Update:

I have added the error message as suggested and I now get the following error:

"The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated"

I will look into this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can only guess that your credentials work in your local environment but don't in your live environment. If your code fails with an exception on the send it will bypass the display code and go directly to your "catch" code.

To debug it, I would put the send after the display to see what happens or more appropriately modify the catch (exception) to grab the error and display that.

```
catch (Exception ex) 
{
          DisplayMessage.Text = "Failed to send email. Error = " + ex.message;
        DisplayMessage.Visible = true;
}
```